# How to put BottomBar for arbitrary page using react-native-navigation Wix library

Tags: react-native, indexing, navigation, bottombar

I am using react-native navigation Wix V2 library. I want to design a login page that is launcher and does not have BottomBar and then go to home page by clicking on an Enter bottom. In home page I want to have a BottomBar menu. The problem is that I only could bring BottomBar menu on my launcher page and I cannot have it on any arbitrary page. How I have to code in index.js?
Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example project: https://github.com/atoami/react-native-navigation-redux-starter-kit

Right at the beginning, it shows a screen where you can choose between starting a `Single Screen App` or a `Tab Based App`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check it.

Comment: I do not know about redux yet. Is it work with redux?

Comment: No, you don't need to use Redux to do what you want to do.